# Animated plot is slowing down after few seconds, how can i keep it running fast?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, animation

I'm building a GUI using tkinter, matplotlib and the animation function that should display 3 different subplots when the plot button is pressed. These subplots have to be updated in real time without any slowdowns to keep the application running smoothly. The y-axis which is data being received via a TCP Connection to an emulator and the x-axis should be the process time from the moment the button is pressed.

Furthermore I succeeded in plotting and displaying the data and basically everything is running but after a few seconds the speed of the plotting , the line drawing and I guess the frame rate drops and it becomes extremely slow as well. I was unable to find a way to start shifting the graph x-axis to the left when enough data is visualized.

I tried a new approach after reading about it, and tried using it but my plots are not displayed as if my data is not there in the first place.

So I would really appreciate the help if someone can help me out to make the visualizing faster and shift-able, any help that could point me to the right way and show me what am doing wrong is greatly appreciated... I am only posting the code parts that are relative to the plotting.

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.font
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.backends._backend_tk import NavigationToolbar2Tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style
style.use('ggplot')

## the lists am plotting st is system temp rp is rotor position and rs is rotor speed time is the x-axis and value is the y-axis
stime_st = []
svalue_st = []
stime_rp = []
svalue_rp = []
stime_rs = []
svalue_rs = []


## this class creates the canvas figure and toolbar
class ploting(tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.init_window()
    def init_window(self):
        global exit_bt
        self.master.title("Plot Display")
        self.pack(fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=True) 
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=self)
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(self.canvas,self) 
        self.toolbar.update()
        close_bt = tkinter.Button(self,relief = 'raised', bg = '#668e99', font =myFont,text = 'Close', command = plot_close, width = 25)
        close_bt.place(relx = 0.999,rely = 0.984, anchor = 'e')
        exit_bt = tkinter.Button(self, font =myFont, bg = '#668e99',text = 'Exit Fullscreen', command = self.toggle, width = 25)
        exit_bt.place(relx = 0.82,rely = 0.984, anchor = 'e')
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side= tkinter.BOTTOM, fill = tkinter.BOTH, expand = True) ## placing the canvas 
        self.canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side= tkinter.TOP, fill = tkinter.BOTH, expand = True)
        self.master.attributes("-fullscreen", True)        
    def exit_fs(self):
        self.master.attributes("-fullscreen", False)
    def enter_fs(self):
        self.master.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
    def toggle(self):
        if exit_bt.config('text')[-1] == 'Exit Fullscreen':
            self.exit_fs()
            exit_bt.config(text = 'Enter Fullscreen')
        else:
            self.enter_fs()
            exit_bt.config(text = 'Exit Fullscreen')

## this function creates the figure, subplots, lines and main window as well as assigning limits and labels
def plot():
    global plot_win
    global fig
    global rs
    global rp
    global st
    global line_st
    global line_rp
    global line_rs
    plt.ion()

    fig = Figure(figsize = (5,5), dpi = 100)
    rs = fig.add_subplot(311, position = [0.08,0.71,0.9,0.22])
    rp = fig.add_subplot(312, position = [0.08,0.39,0.9,0.22])
    st = fig.add_subplot(313, position = [0.08,0.07,0.9,0.22])

    line_rs, = rs.plot(stime_rs,svalue_rs,'k-')   
    rs.set_xlabel("Time(s)")
    rs.set_ylabel("Speed(RPM)")
    rs.set_title("Rotor Speed")

    line_rp, = rp.plot(stime_rp,svalue_rp,'k-')
    rp.set_xlabel("Time(s)")
    rp.set_ylabel("Position(DEG)")
    rp.set_title("Rotor Position")
    rp.set_ylim(0,360)

    line_st, = st.plot(stime_st,svalue_st,'k-')
    st.set_xlabel("Time(s)")
    st.set_ylabel("Tempreture(C°)")
    st.set_title("System Tempreture")
    st.set_ylim(0,75)    
    plot_bt.config(state = 'disabled') ## this is irrelevant its from the main page of the GUI
    newTime = time.process_time() ## time in seconds from the moment the plot is drawn
    plot_win = tkinter.Tk()
    plot_win.geometry("1280x800")
    plot_win.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",plot_close)
    app = ploting(plot_win) ## am creating the figure and canvas... etc
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval = 100, blit = True)
## ani is calling the animation function with blit to increase the speed and reduce unwanted drawings
    app.mainloop() 

## in this function if a connection to tcp is made that means i have data and in that case it will append the time and values into the list and set the ydata and xdata

def animate(i):
    if conn_tcp.is_set():
        stime_rs.append(newTime)
        stime_rp.append(newTime)
        stime_st.append(newTime)
        svalue_rs.append(value_rs)
        svalue_rp.append(value_rp)
        svalue_st.append(value_st)        
        line_rs.set_ydata(svalue_rs)
        line_rp.set_ydata(svalue_rp)
        line_st.set_ydata(svalue_st)
        line_rs.set_xdata(stime_rs)
        line_rp.set_xdata(stime_rp)
        line_st.set_xdata(stime_st)
    return line_rs,line_rp,line_st,
```

Comment: Formatting improvements, grammatical improvements

Comment: Can you reduce this to a [mcve]? Also, what is `ion()` doing here? Maybe that causes trouble, but at least it is superfluous when embedding in tk.

Comment: sorry for my English, i actually figured out what my problem was, i was appending the values in the animate function instead of the function that reads the values and update it,i kept the code as it is and changed only the appending and that solved my performance problem; as for the shifting of the x-axis while it updates i had no limits for my x axis and my ticks weren't set so i just added that to my animate function and now it works , finally ion() to allow interactions with the plot but it is also irrelevant i removed it already.                         thank you guys for taking the time.